# fatal error CVT1100: duplicate resource. type:ICON, name:1 (C++, Visual Studio C++ 2010)

Tags: c++, resources, icons

I tried to add custom icons (13x13 dimention) to a project.

I cannot find why I cannot load icon.

> CVTRES : fatal error CVT1100: duplicate resource. type:ICON, name:1,
>   language:0x0409 LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion
>   to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

Some information from resource.h:

```
#define IDI_LOGO   16   //0x10 - no problem here
...
/* Bitmaps */
#define IDB_LOGO            200
#define IDB_GOOD            201
#define IDB_EVIL            202

/* Icons */
#define IDI_TERRAIN 90 // problem starts here
#define IDI_ELEV    91
#define IDI_DRAWREPLACE 92
#define IDI_DRAWFILL    93
#define IDI_DRAWBRUSH   94
```

common.rc:

```
#include "resource.h"
/* Bitmaps */ // no problem
#define IDB_LOGO            200
#define IDB_GOOD            201
#define IDB_EVIL            202

/* Icons */ // problem:
#define IDI_TERRAIN 90
#define IDI_ELEV    91
#define IDI_DRAWREPLACE 92
#define IDI_DRAWFILL    93
#define IDI_DRAWBRUSH   94
```

file2.rc:

```
#include "resource.h"
IDI_LOGO    ICON    DISCARDABLE "res/swgbts.ico"






#include "resource.h"
IDI_LOGO    ICON    DISCARDABLE "res/aokts.ico"
```

I tried to change the id of the IDI_TERRAIN and other icons, did not help.

According this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1kw34cb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
I tried to change the number, did not help

Note that if I comment out the problematic lines, IDI_LOGO is loaded.
Any help?

The error is in resource.h
Visual Studio C++ 2010, Windows XP

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue. Looks like it is **impossible** to merge `.rc`. files if they both have icons. Despite the non-overlapping numbering scheme you might have.

See below explanation from Microsoft: Gary Chang has posted this [interesting explanation](https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/121866-fatal-error-cvt1100-duplicate-resource-type-icon-name-1-langua) elsewhere on the net:

> The following is more detail info on the root cause of this problem:
>   "Basically what's happening is that Icon resources are composed of two
>   different Win32 resource types `C RT_GROUP_ICON` and `RT_ICON`. You can think
>   of `RT_GROUP_ICON` as a directory of `RT_ICON` resources. The `RT_ICON`
>   resources are the actual icon images.
>
> The VC resource editor tries to simplify this for you in a single icon
>   resource entity and under the hood handles some things like creation and ID
>   naming of the individual `RT_ICON` resources (the #1 you're seeing in this
>   case). The VC resource editor was also created back in the day when it was
>   only possible to have a single `.rc` file in a given `.exe` or `.dll`. Changes
>   have since been made in the command line tools to allow use of multiple .rc
>   files to contribute to a given `.exe` or `.dll` but I don't believe the
>   resource editor implementation was ever revisited with this new possibility
>   in mind, at least from the standpoint of the way it handles icons.
>
> So with the current VC++ compiler,the only thing that can be done in this
>   case if you want to have multiple resource files is to keep all icon (and
>   cursor) resources in a single `.rc` file. That will let the VC resource
>   editor keep all the `RT_ICON` identifiers unique."
>
> Wish this helps and thanks for your understanding!
>   Best regards,
>
> Gary Chang
>   Microsoft Community Support

Comment: I now store the icons as raw `RCDATA` in the resource files that are "included" by the "main" project.

Now `CVTRES` can merge the compiled resource files just fine.

I also have included dialog resources but unlike icons `CVTRES` is fine with that.

The hard part is to obtain `HICON`. For this I have to call `CreateIconFromResourceEx` with the bits obtained from `LookupIconIdFromDirectoryEx`.

And before that, the pointer to the raw ICO file bytes (from the resource) has to be obtained via functions `FindResource`, `LoadResource`, `LockResource`, `VirtualProtect` etc.

Comment: The funnies thing here is this quote from _Gary Chang_, from the link above:
> _So with current VC resource compiler, I am afraid there is no way to
 do this, **but our product team members will fix it in the future.**_

It was said exactly 14 (fourteen) years ago. But the absolutely same problem still exist in 2019.

Comment: Even funnier is that nobody (that includes me) has filed a bug report. So I just did.

Comment: Stay in touch for any news related)

Comment: There was already a ticket for that:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/363156/visual-studio-2017-prof-1557-cvt1100-duplicate-res.html
And https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ca805bad-9893-483b-8482-6e6ccaa0a4f8/cvtres-fatal-error-cvt1100-duplicate-resource-typeicon-name1-language0x0409-link-?forum=vclanguage

Comment: The problem is more in the linker then in the rc compiler. Multiple .rc files create multiple .res files. If you merge these .res files first with a tool and then add the .res file to the vc project instead of the individual .rc files the problem is solved. Unfortunately I have not yet made these tools public.

Comment: @ArnoudMulder, it is never too late to publish it on Github. Come to think about it, I have converted my icons to source code, in a similar way as what the `xxd -i` tool does, that see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707183/script-tool-to-convert-file-to-c-c-source-code-array

Answer (score 3):

I Solved the problem.

I have moved content of one .rc file to main rc file. The compiler had problem to include ICONs from two resources. I have no idea why but this is clear and simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it just has duplicated resource IDs.

```
#define IDB_LOGO            200
...
#define IDB_EVIL            200
```

Changing one of them would resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in VC 2015 but at small changes error

> 2>CVTRES : fatal error CVT1100: duplicate resource.  type:DIALOG,
> name:564, language:0x041B
> 2>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during
> conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

I'm having any *.rc files in *.vcxproj and my resource.h is:

```
#define IDC_1  100
#define IDR_1  101
//etc
//about 
#define IDXXX_XXX  12000
//and
#define ID_1 32769
//etc
```

I replaced defines from 100 to 999 after "IDXXX_XXX" renumber and rebuild.
So problem is solved.